# Fast Fourier cosine transform in two dimension by using FFTW3 library

Tags: c++

Please help me this problem.
I am trying to use fast fourier cosine transform in two dimensional by using FFTW3 library . In my case, i really need to transform with a lot of point. When i set number of points in x and y direction equal to n0*n1=512*512, my program run correctly. However, i set number of points equal to n0*n1=1024*1024, i got the message "segmentation fault". The problem, may be, come from memory with three arrays double in[N], in2[N], out[N](here N=n0*n1), which are built.

So i have tried to replace arrays by vector but it seems to be not suitable for FFTW3 library.
My program is run on laptop with RAM 4GB and core i3.

Could you give for me a advice for my case?

I appreciate with any your ideal.
Thank you so much.

Here is my program

```
enter code here
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <fftw3.h>

using namespace std;
int main() {

    int n0=1024;
    int n1=1024;

    int N=n0*n1;

    double in[N], in2[N], out[N];

    fftw_plan p, q;
    int i,j;
    p = fftw_plan_r2r_2d(n0,n1, in, out, FFTW_REDFT00, FFTW_REDFT00, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    for (i =0;i <n0;i++){
        for (j=0;j<n1;j++)
        { 
            in[i*n0+j] = cos(2.0*M_PI*(double)i/(n0 - 1))+cos(2.0*M_PI*(double)j/(n1 - 1)); 
        }
    }

    fftw_execute(p);
    q = fftw_plan_r2r_2d(n0,n1, out, in2, FFTW_REDFT00, FFTW_REDFT00, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(q);

    for (i =0;i<n0;i++){
        for (j=0;j<n1;j++)
        {
            printf("%3d %9.5f %9.5f\n", i*n0+j, in[i*n0+j], in2[i*n0+j]/(2.0*(double)(n0 - 1))/(2.0*(double)(n1 - 1)));
        }
    }
  fftw_destroy_plan(p); fftw_destroy_plan(q); fftw_cleanup();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Variable length arrays are forbidden by C++ standard. Some compilers do support them, but it is not a good idea to use them because it makes your program not portable(that is, `N` must be a compile time constant if you create an array of size `N` on stack).
2. `in`, `in2` and `out` arrays are allocated on stack. The default stack size varies for different OS, but it is usually a few megabytes(8 MB on Linux). It is not enough to hold them. That's why you get a SEGFAULT.
3. To fix this problem, you can allocate arrays dynamically:

   ```
   double* in = new double[N];
   double* in2 = new double[N];
   double* out = new double[N];
   ```
4. Do not forget to delete them when they are not needed anymore(at the end of the program in this case) to avoid memory leaks:

   ```
   delete[] in;
   delete[] in2;
   delete[] out;
   ```

Comment: More than i expected. Thank you so much, ILoveCoding. I love coding too.

Comment: Downvoted, because `new[]` isn't really a good advice to a beginner. He already had the correct idea (`vector`).

Answer (score 0):

FFTW3 will happily accept points from a vector, you just need to get a pointer. Call `vector::data()` to get that pointer.

Comment: Could you please give me more detail how to point to vector by using FFTW library? Thank you.

Comment: @LucNguyen: Instead of `double in[N]`, use `std::vector<double> in(N)`. Instead of passing `in` to `fftw_plan_r2r_2d()`, pass `in.data()`.

Comment: Thank you so much. My program run correctly by using pointer vector  std::vector<double> in(N,0.0); and in.data()